# Is there any stackexchange site for Human resource Q&A?

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal

One of my friend is a HR in a company... He saw my profile on stackoverflow which is a programming Q&A... On behalf of my friend i really want to know any Human resource Q&A site under stackexchange? Any suggestion

Comment: @ChedurPandian apparently that proposal did not manage it? Have you found any alternatives?

Comment: There's [Workplace Stack Exchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) site, just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why didn't you use the search on Area 51?

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2900/human-resources

Answer (score 2):

The Area 51 proposal in the accepted answer has been removed because of insufficient activity. Since it's not likely to 'incubate' into a site under the new rules, consider asking your Human Resources question on an existing site in the network:

[The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com) covers a lot of [topics](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) within the Human Resources area, and while most questions about [human resources](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-resources) there are asked from the perspective of the 'other' side (an employee interacting *with* the Human Resources department), it's entirely possible a question on behalf of the Human Resources department would fit. (It's rather hard to search for specific examples.)

Legal HR questions might fit on [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com), they have quite a few [employment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment)-related questions.

As always, be sure to read the Help Center article "What topics can I ask about here?" (/help/on-topic) on the target sites and any relevant Meta posts linked therein, before actually asking your question.